# React Redux doesn't update UI

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

React-Redux doesn't update UI when store changes.

I expect *{this.props.isLogged}* to get changed dynamically when *Change button* is clicked.

I searched tons of materials but I cannot find why the text doesn't change when button is clicked.

**Index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducers from "./reducers";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const store = createStore(
  reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "./actions";

class App extends React.Component {
  changeText = () => {
    this.props.loginUser();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.props.isLogged}</span>
        <button onClick={this.changeText}>Change</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state /*, ownProps*/) => {
  return {
    isLogged: state.isLogged
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = { loginUser };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**./src/reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { LOGIN_USER } from "../actions";

function userReducer(state = { isLogged: false }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_USER:
      return { isLogged: !state.isLogged };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const reducers = combineReducers({
  userReducer
});

export default reducers;
```

**./src/actions/index.js**

```
export const LOGIN_USER = "LOGIN_USER";
export function loginUser(text) {
  return { type: LOGIN_USER };
}
```

Comment: you don't pass text to loginUser in your component. But you don't use text in your action either, so delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out..
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-doesnt-update-ui-vj3eh

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  userReducer //It is actually userReducer: userReducer
});
```

As you assiging your **UserReducer** to userReducer prop, you will have to fetch the same way in **mapStateToProps**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state /*, ownProps*/) => {
  return {
    isLogged: state.userReducer.isLogged
  };
};
```

Also, **isLogged** prop is a Boolean variable.. So you are gonna have to use toString().

```
<span>{this.props.isLogged.toString()}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `combineReducers`, the isLogged boolean lives in `state.userReducer.isLogged`.

Consider changing `combineReducers` to `combineReducers({ user: userReducer })` and accessing the flag with `state.user.isLogged`.